# javascript - multidimensional array contains 4 items but length indicates: 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I made a multidimensional array today which creates 4 new arrays within the first array. when I console.log my array it says that there are 0 items in it, but i do see my 4 arrays each with other items. See the console.log below for a clearer image:

[image]

```
 vm.allGroupsInClassifications = [];
 datacontext.graph.getAllGroups().then(function (data) {

            var groups = [];

            // get all clasification names and put them in the array and create a new array
            for (var k in vm.classificationNames) {
                var groupName = vm.classificationNames[k];
                groups[groupName] = new Array();
            }

            // go through all the groups and sort them based on their classification
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                if (data[i].classification != null) {
                    modifyGroupContent(data[i], groups, 0);
                }
                else if (data[i].classification == null) 
                    modifyGroupContent(data[i], groups, 1);
                }


            vm.allGroupsInClassifications = groups;
            console.log(vm.allGroupsInClassifications);
```

any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have no indexes. `groups[groupName] = new Array();` won't add an item to your array, because all your `groupName` variables are not numbers. And thus you have an array-object-like thing.

If your `groupName`'s were say 0,1,2 and 3, when you `console.log` the object, you will get the last number+1 (in this case 4).

Here you can access your arrays with the keys - so in this case `vm.allGroupsInClassifications['Confidential']` will return your array.

But since you don't have actual numeric indexes, the length of your object-array thing is 0.

Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

It's because your array is incorrect. You have an array with keys :

```
[
    "Algemeen" : [...],
    "Confidential" : [...]
]
```

This is incorrect, as arrays can't have keys. Javascript being Javascript, it allows you to define it nonetheless, but when you ask for its length, it's quite unable to answer and says 0. It should be an object :

```
{
    "Algemeen" : [...],
    "Confidential" : [...]
}
```

If you really want to keep an array of arrays, remove the keys :

```
 [ [...],[...] ]
```

Now the length is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your try to use an object, like an array.
If you want to detect the amount of your keys in the object,
use this:

```
Object.keys(myObject).length
```